# Is there a way to convert the html class and target link text to display as a normal link text

Tags: html, css, angular6, chat, message

I am using a innerhtml to bind the chat message in my application. From server side I sent a message I am trying to convert a html content to normal link content in angular 6.

```
<a href="https://helloworld.com/test&quot;" class="linkified" target="_blank">https://helloworld.com/test"</a>
```

In client side I got the output as

```
https://helloworld.com/test" class="linkified" target="_blank">https://helloworld.com/test" class="linkified" target="_blank">" class="linkified" target="_blank">https://helloworld.com/test" class="linkified" target="_blank">https://helloworld.com/test
```

How to display a normal hyperlink in my chat window. 
My output should be https://helloworld.com/test"

My chat window is designed as

```
<p [innerHTML]="msgObj.message" class="mr-2 pr-1 mb-0"></p>
```

When message is received in our application. In api it is shown as

```
{"message": "<a href="<a href="https://helloworld.com/test&quot" class="linkified" target="_blank">https://helloworld.com/test&amp;quot</a>;" class="linkified" target="_blank"><a href="https://helloworld.com/test&quot;</a>" class="linkified" target="_blank">https://helloworld.com/test"</a></a>"}
```

Comment: No problems appear https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sasbve

Comment: but I added the output here. Its not working in my application

Comment: There must be another problem,the code is running as seen, please share more information with us

Comment: edited my question with json body of the message received

Comment: WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see http://g.co/ng/security#xss  Got the warning along with the response body

Comment: The problem is with nested a href tag. so the output of client side looks like the above mentioned